# PHP INSERT Error When I Don't Attach any File In Upload Input

Tags: php, file-upload, insert, pdo, prepared-statement

I have an error inserting some content in a Postgresql Database when I don't attach any file. I have a form with some inputs that I insert in one table and one input to upload multiple files and some info to other table.

The error with empty upload input:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\arn\upload.php on line 60**

**LINE 60:** $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO arn_info (arn , modelos , familias , problema , solucao) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");

**MY FORM:**

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM arn_info");

    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($sth){
        $row = $sth->fetch();

        echo '<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" />';
        echo 'ARN: <input type="text" name="arn" /><br />';
        echo 'Familias: <input type="text" name="familias" /> <br />';
        echo 'Problema: <textarea class="tinymce" name="problema" cols="30" rows="10">';
        echo '</textarea>';
        echo 'Solução: <textarea class="tinymce" name="solucao" cols="30" rows="10">';
        echo '</textarea>';

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">';
        echo 'Anexos: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" class="multi" id="userfile">';

        echo '<input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value="ADD ARN">';
        echo '</form>';

     }
?>
```

**MY UPLOAD AND INSERT PHP:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $uploadDir = 'uploads/';

    $fileArn = $_POST['arn'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $arn = $_POST['arn'];
    $modelos = $_POST['modelos'];
    $familias = $_POST['familias'];
    $problema = $_POST['problema'];
    $solucao = $_POST['solucao'];

    foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error)
    {      
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {           
            $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$key];
            $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$key];
            $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$key];

            $folderName = $_POST['arn'] . "/";

            if (!file_exists ( $uploadDir . $folderName )) {
            $arnFolder = mkdir($uploadDir . $folderName, 0777);
            }

            $filePath = $uploadDir . $folderName  . basename($fileName);

            $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

            if (!$result) {
            echo "Error adding Files";
            exit;
            }

            include 'includes/connection.php';

            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
            $filePath = addslashes($filePath);

            if (!file_exists ($fileName)) {

            $info = array ($fileName , $fileSize , $fileType , $filePath , $fileArn );

            $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO upload2 (name, size, type, path , id_arn ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
            $sth->execute($info);
            }
        }

        } //END OF LOOP

        $parametros = array($arn,$modelos,$familias,$problema,$solucao);

        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO arn_info (arn , modelos , familias , problema , solucao) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");

        $sth->execute($parametros); 

        if($sth){
            header("location: admin.php?inserted=1");
        }
}
?>
```

**IF I Attach One or More Files All Works Fine !**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, the above is good general advice, but not the cause of your issue. The issue is caused by the fact that you include the connection *inside* the loop which will never be executed if there are no file uploads. Here's the fix:

```
<?php

include 'includes/connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $uploadDir = 'uploads/';

    $fileArn = $_POST['arn'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $arn = $_POST['arn'];
    $modelos = $_POST['modelos'];
    $familias = $_POST['familias'];
    $problema = $_POST['problema'];
    $solucao = $_POST['solucao'];

    foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error)
    {      
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {           
            $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$key];
            $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$key];
            $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$key];

            $folderName = $_POST['arn'] . "/";

            if (!file_exists ( $uploadDir . $folderName )) {
            $arnFolder = mkdir($uploadDir . $folderName, 0777);
            }

            $filePath = $uploadDir . $folderName  . basename($fileName);

            $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

            if (!$result) {
            echo "Error adding Files";
            exit;
            }

            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
            $filePath = addslashes($filePath);

            if (!file_exists ($fileName)) {

            $info = array ($fileName , $fileSize , $fileType , $filePath , $fileArn );

            $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO upload2 (name, size, type, path , id_arn ) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
            $sth->execute($info);
            }
        }

        } //END OF LOOP

        $parametros = array($arn,$modelos,$familias,$problema,$solucao);

        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO arn_info (arn , modelos , familias , problema , solucao) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");

        $sth->execute($parametros); 

        if($sth){
            header("location: admin.php?inserted=1");
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\arn
>   \upload.php on line 60

It seems your  $sth is not an object. If you want to see a more descriptive message, you'll have to tell PDO that you actually want to see errors. Try the following (probably in 'connection.php'):

```
<?php
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

That will make sure PDO will output a message.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `$dbh` is nowhere to be found in your file. So the variable doesn't exist and you can't call the `prepare()` method on it.

Comment: I have an include where I defined $dbh ,if I attach files the code works

Comment: like said in another answer, the include is done at the wrong place.